# modrewrite with regex making it simpler

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Hi all I am trying to clean-up my mod rewrite for pages like this:

```
sales/provider/all/name=asc/page=1
sales/provider/all/name=desc/page=1
```

Currently I am using a new line for everything like that:

```
  RewriteRule ^sales/provider/all/name=asc/page=([0-9]+)?$ /sales.php?sort=name&order=asc&view=provider&provider_id=all&page=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^sales/provider/all/name=desc/page=([0-9]+)?$ /sales.php?sort=name&order=desc&view=provider&provider_id=all&page=$1 [N,NC,QSA]
```

What is the simplest way to get the "name" and "asc" or "desc" using regex so I can then have only one rule instead of loads of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^sales/provider/all/name=(asc|desc)/page=([0-9]+)?$ /sales.php?sort=name&order=$1&view=provider&provider_id=all&page=$2 [N,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Oh wow I love how simple yet still descriptive this one is, perfect thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should capture as much as you can from original URI rather than repeating it:

```
RewriteRule ^sales/(provider)/(all)/([^=]+)=([^/]+)/(page=[0-9]+)/?$ /sales.php?sort=$3&order=$4&view=$1&provider_id=$2&$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```